# For what is it used -E flag with -cpp? (gfortran preprocessing options)

Tags: gfortran

I'm using the following options:

```
touch foo.f90; gfortran -cpp -E -dM foo.f90
```

, but when I remove the -E flag I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I used 'touch' the file is empty.

Comment: Please show the **exact** code, even if it is just a Helloworld example. Make sure that the error message comes really from that exact code you will show. Make sure there is a `program` in your code.

Comment: Be aware that touch does *not*  create a Helloworld example, it makes an empty file. Also, please use `LANG="C"` to get English error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-E` flag is described in [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

> If you use the -E option, nothing is done except preprocessing. Some
> of these options make sense only together with -E because they cause
> the preprocessor output to be unsuitable for actual compilation.

It makes the compiler to print the preprocessed source code instead of compiling it. That means preprocessed by `cpp`, the C preprocessor.

If your source code is not a valid Fortran program, then trying to actually  compile it (without the `-E` flag) naturally leads to some kind of error message.

Comment: Thank you for the info.